# Cannot load resources in apache2 server

Tags: javascript, css, apache

I am trying to get a webapp to run with the following structure:

index.html

```
|__css
   |_____style.css
|__js
   |_____script.js
|__images
    |___img.png
```

When I put it in /var/www and run the application.

The console outputs the following error:

```
GET http://localhost/projectMap/css/style.css 403 (Forbidden) localhost/:9
GET http://localhost/projectMap/js/mapHelper.js 403 (Forbidden) localhost/:54
GET http://localhost/projectMap/js/yqlHelper.js 403 (Forbidden) localhost/:55
GET http://localhost/projectMap/js/util.js 403 (Forbidden) localhost/:56
GET http://localhost/projectMap/js/app.js 403 (Forbidden)
```

Obviously it is not allowing access to the scripts and the css files.

Please tell me how to correct this error.

Comment: Does your apache user (usually `www-data`) have read permission for those files?

Answer (score -1):

THANKS!

I solved it by

chmod 777 /var/www/projectMap

and changing permissions on all the folders!!

Comment: I'm downvoting this because `777` is **way** too open! You don't need to give *that* much permissions - It's actually more harmful...

Comment: Figure out which user your apache is running under and which user actually owns the `projectMap` folder - then add one to the others group to give permissions only to the users who really *need* it.